# How to make a Flutter quarter box edge?

Tags: flutter

I need to make a Flutter comment tree. I need to show the connection with the lines with this tree.
So I need to create a structure like this.

[image]

But I'm not sure how to create this shape, can you help with this?

Which widget should I use to create such a shape?

[image]

Comment: CustomPainter with the cubicTo method: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/cubicTo.html

Comment: CustomPainter with the drawArc method: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawArc.html